# Does foursquare venue/explore API support locale parameter?

Tags: foursquare

For Example:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?v=20130815&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&open&ll=13.7429128535%2C+100.6018416093&section=topPicks&locale=en&sortByDistance=0

I set locale parameter to `en` but i still get Thai name in my POI.
Do we have any way to get only english POI ?